# Best practice for logging callback durations and execution times in ROS

Tags: ros, control, logging, performance

I'm wondering if there are any best practices for logging callback durations and execution times in ROS? As my system evolves and implementation is changed, I'd like to be able to monitor the execution time of logic in the critical planning and control subsystems of my robot.

The simplest method seems to be to add RCLCPP_DEBUG() statements in callbacks as necessary and analyze the /rosout topic in a rosbag afterwards.

Are there any other ideas on this, or has anyone come across examples in other open source codebases that they could share?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the functionality you are looking for is provided by [ros2_tracing](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_tracing).

For a quick overview have a look at the ROS World 2021 presentation: [video](https://vimeo.com/652633418), [slides](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_tracing/blob/rolling/doc/2021-10-20_ROS_World_2021_-_Tracing_ROS_2_with_ros2_tracing.pdf).